Cypress test succeeded on local test but failed on amplify build
succeeded local test
failed on amplify build

|
yarn build-storybook -o ./storybook-static
pm2 start "serve storybook-static -l 6006"
wait-on "http://localhost:6006/iframe.html?id=pages-login-createname--create-name"
yarn workspace @myapp/app cypress run --spec "cypress/e2e/components/CreateName/FirstNameInput.cy.ts" --reporter mochawesome --reporter-options "reportDir=cypress/report2/mochawesome-report,overwrite=false,html=false,json=true,timestamp=mmddyyyy_HHMMss"
pm2 stop all

This is the "amplify.yml" test phase commands.
cypress test code
I want to know why is this happen.
I tried cy.wait(5000) to wait for the iframe address to be started but it didn`t work.
I might think the build command should be modified to start the test on correct address. But this is only my opinion.
And i also need to tell you that this is a component tests which created by using e2e env on cypress
Please help!

Please post your code instead of including images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557
